# Is there any downside to using pre-multiplication order for matrices in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

The old matrix stack in OpenGL dictated that the matrix multiplication order had to be post-multiplication. Modern OpenGL defers these matrix operations to the shader, where we're now free to choose to use `operator*(vec4,mat4)` instead of `operator*(mat4,vec4)`. I happen to like pre-multiplication better, as I find that it makes code more readable. E.g. with post-multiplication we have

```
mat4 mvp = vp * m;
```

while with pre-multiplication it becomes

```
mat4 mvp = m * vp;
```

which makes more sense to me.

Anyways, my question is: Is there any downside to this? Other than OpenGL people not being used to it? There doesn't seem to be any change in performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The old matrix stack in OpenGL dictated that the matrix multiplication order had to be post-multiplication.

No it didn't. The fixed function matrix stack would have worked just as fine with left associative multiplication (e.g. `glRotate :: M = R · M`) assuming row major matrices and row vectors, i.e. writing everything transposed. In fact mathematically this makes zero difference, it's exactly the same.

> There doesn't seem to be any change in performance.

It's not a question about performance, but convenience. Most mathematical folk (computer scientists, physicists, mathematicians) are used to use column vectors and to read expressions right to left. It's common notation and that's why its done that way.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can do what you want.. Most people think of vectors as columns.. but you can use row vectors.. However, you should compute things like:

```
mat4 modelView = view * model
```

in the application. If you would compute it in the vertex shader.. it is evaluated for each vertex.

Comment: In principle, it seems that the GLSL compiler could spot arithmetic between two uniforms, (much like two constants) and optimize to do that work outside the shading processors... ?

Comment: Most probably you're right. I think it's good to rely on the compiler :) however i cannot turn the suspiciousness off entirely.